# C# callback from C++ gives access violation

Tags: c#, c++, callback, unmanaged

EDIT(Thank you ildjarn!):
Solved by changing delegate(and Callback function signature to match) to

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void InstallStatusDel([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string Mesg, int Status);
```

Original post:

I have a problem with a .net application written in C# that calls functions in a C dll. I've looked at other threads with similar questions but I must be missing something different. When I debug this in C# I am able to hit a breakpoint in InstallStatusCallback but when execution exits InstallStatusCallback there is an AccessViolationException. I've tried debugging with C and the access violation occurs before execution returns back from the callback. Thank you for any input.

Project settings in C dll are set to use __cdecl by default. In C DLL land the following code is in place:

```
typedef void (__cdecl *StatusCallback)(const char* Mesg, int Status);
__declspec(dllexport) int Install(void* thing1, void* thing2, void* thing3, StatusCallback Func);


int Install(void* thing1, void* thing2, void* thing3, StatusCallback Func)
{
    Func("msg", 3);
    return 0;
}
```

In C# I have:

```
public partial class InstallerStatus : Form
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void InstallStatusDel(StringBuilder Mesg, int Status);

    public static extern int Install(IntPtr thing1, IntPtr thing2, IntPtr thing3, InstallStatusDel Func);
    [DllImport("myDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    private IntPtr mThing1;
    private IntPtr mThing2;
    private InstallStatusDel mInstallStatusFunc;
    private BackgroundWorker mInstallWorker;

    public InstallerStatus(IntPtr pThing1, IntPtr pThing2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mThing1 = pThing1;
        mThing2 = pThing2;
        mInstallStatusFunc = InstallStatusCallback;

        mProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
        mProgressBar.Maximum = 100;
        mProgressBar.Value = 0;

        mInstallWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        mInstallWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(InstallWork);
        mInstallWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(InstallWork_Completed);
    }

    private void InstallWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Install(mThing1, mThing2, IntPtr.Zero, mInstallStatusFunc);
    }

    private void InstallWork_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void InstallStatusCallback(StringBuilder PartName, int Status)
    {
    }

    private void InstallLoad_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mInstallWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `InstallStatusDel`'s first parameter a `StringBuilder` rather than a `string`? `StringBuilder` is for _mutable_ strings. In any case, you may want to add `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` to said parameter.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by changing delegate(and Callback function signature to match) to

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void InstallStatusDel([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string Mesg, int Status);
```

Thank you ildjarn!